# Error mounting NTFS disk

Tags: mount, disk

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/shashank/New Volume:
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda5" "/media/shashank/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 14:
 The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata kept in Windows 
cache, refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not 
permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and 
shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the 
volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option
```

I'm getting this error whenever I'm trying to access the Local Disk

Comment: Have you shut Windows down fully?

Comment: It's clearly written here - boot and fully shutdown your windows (no fast reboot, no hibernation)

Comment: I've done it....tried to shut down also... done it couple of times!!

Still it's same

Comment: Is this drive "New Volume" a Windows C: drive, or just a NTFS data disk? Do you also have Windows installed?

Comment: It's not C: drive for sure....dont really know if it's NTFS or not

It's F: drive in Windows

Comment: In Windows, open an admin command prompt window and type `chkdsk /f f:` and then retry the mount in Ubuntu. Start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @muru the answers cited don't apply to this question, as the problematic drive is the F: drive, not the C: drive. This question should be reopened.

Comment: @heynnema in my case, I have seen that hibernation/fast boot marks all filesystems opened by Windows as dirty, not just the one that Windows is installed on. And this happens with a plain shutdown as well (which, unless fastboot is disabled, does the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a Windows operating system on the drive turn off fast startup

1. Type Control Panel in the search box.
2. Click Control Panel.
3. Click Power Options.
4. Click Choose what the power buttons do.
5. Click Change settings that are currently unavailable.
6. Scroll down to Shutdown settings and uncheck Turn on fast startup.
7. Click Save changes.

If this does not work launch an administrator command prompt and run `chkdsk /f` and follow the prompts